# What is the advantage of a fluted barrel on a hunting rifle?

Tags: hunting, guns, rifles

As I look for a new hunting rifle, I see that some have fluted barrels, such as the Mossberg Patriot for example and some do not.

What would the advantage of a fluted barrel be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fluted barrel has two advantages,

1. The **flutes make the barrel lighter** and thus easier to carry for long periods while hunting.
2. **More surface area means that the barrel cools down faster**. As barrels heat up they lose their accuracy to a degree. Normally while hunting this isn't a big deal, but when sighting in or practicing this needs to be taken into account.

Overall this seems to be more common on hunting rifles where a lighter rifle is easier to hunt with.

Comment: The cooling isn't necessarily much advantage since it will also heat up faster.